# Jquery datepicker() focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got some screens that are turning date input fields into datepickers using jquery's `datepicker()`. I've also got a script that runs through the page and focuses the first input field. What I would like to have happen is if the first field is a datepicker, then focus just the input, don't show the datepicker() ui calendar, but when you click inside the input, the ui calendar shows up. Does that make sense?

Thanks!